# Using execl with multiple child processes

Tags: c, file, process, exec, fork

I'm trying to create a process that creates several child processes, each calling the [`file()`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) function.

Here is what I have so far:

- The parent writes a list of files into a pipe
- The child processes redirect the pipe to stdin and redirect stdout to another pipe and each `exec` `file`.
- The parent waits for the termination of the child processes using `select` and reads from the relevant pipe (containing the output of the file function).

When I use only one child process, everything is working great: The child terminates with all output in the pipe, and the parent reads it. However, when I use 2 child processes, they don't terminate; The file function gets into "sleeping" mode, waiting for more input. The parent is then also blocked, waiting for the children to terminate.

I've created a minimal contained example of the two pipe version:

```
#define NUM_CHILDREN (2)
//pipes from parent to children
int pipeP2C[NUM_CHILDREN][2];
//pipes from children to parent
int pipeC2P[NUM_CHILDREN][2];

int children_ids[NUM_CHILDREN];

int main()
{
//create pipes from parent to children and vice versa
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; ++i){
    pipe(pipeP2C[i]);
    pipe(pipeC2P[i]);
}

//create first child
//Create initial g_parLevel child processes
pid_t pid;
int numForks = 0;
do
{
    pid = fork();
    // Parent process should count how many children it has
    if (pid > 0) {
        children_ids[numForks] = pid;
        ++numForks;
    }
    //child process also writes its' own pid to children_ids.
    else {
        children_ids[numForks] = (int)getpid();
    }
}
//Call fork again from parent process, if it doesn't have g_parLevel children already.
while (pid > 0 && numForks < NUM_CHILDREN);

//Now we have NUM_CHILDREN child processes, their ids are kept in the parent process, and each
//of them has (at least) it's own id kept in the suitable index in children_ids.

//parent - write to the children
if (pid > 0){
    //Iterate over all children
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; ++i)
    {
        std::string str = "/bin/ls";
        //close reading end
        close(pipeP2C[i][0]);
        //write to child
        write(pipeP2C[i][1], str.c_str(), (int)str.length());
        close(pipeP2C[i][1]);
    }

    //wait for the children to terminate
    int terminatedChildren = 0;
    while (terminatedChildren < NUM_CHILDREN)
    {
        int status;
        int terminatedChild = wait(&status);
        ++terminatedChildren;

        //read from the terminated child
        int childIndex = children_ids[0] == terminatedChild ? 0 : 1;

        //close writing end
        close(pipeC2P[childIndex][1]);
        char buf[2048];
        read(pipeC2P[childIndex][0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipeC2P[childIndex][0]);
        std::cerr<<"output from child "<<childIndex<<" is:\n"<<buf<<std::endl;
    }
}

//child process
if (pid == 0)
{
    //find the pipe to read from.
    int childPid = getpid();
    int childIndex = children_ids[0] == childPid ? 0 : 1;
    std::cerr<<"in child "<<childPid<<" index "<<childIndex<<std::endl;
    //wait until the parent has written data
    fd_set rfds;
    int ready;
    while(true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        //we are interested in the reading end
        FD_SET(pipeP2C[childIndex][0], &rfds);
        ready = select(pipeP2C[childIndex][0] + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ready > 0){
            std::cerr<<"ready"<<std::endl;

            //close the relevant writing end of the pipe from parent to child
            close(pipeP2C[childIndex][1]);
            //redirect input to stdin
            dup2(pipeP2C[childIndex][0], 0);
            close(pipeP2C[childIndex][0]);

            //close relevant reading end of the pipe from child to parent
            close(pipeC2P[childIndex][0]);
            //redirect output from stdout
            dup2(pipeC2P[childIndex][1], 1);
            close(pipeC2P[childIndex][1]);

            execl("/usr/bin/file","file", "-n", "-f", "-", (char *)NULL);

            //should never get here
            std::cerr<<"file failed"<<std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Why doesn't it wait

Comment: AFAIR there _is no way_ to 'unbuffer' pipes. At least on Linux. Sorry. You can `setvbuf` all you want, but the OS will keep buffering in the IPC stage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. What's unclear to me is why does a child process behave differently when it's the only child process, and when there's another child process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing file descriptors from other processes. When you `fork` your children still have references to the file descriptors from the other children.

Close them before you do processing. Something like:

```
for(int k=0;k<NUM_CHILDREN;k++){
    if(k!=childIndex){
        close(pipeP2C[k][0]);
        close(pipeP2C[k][1]);
        close(pipeC2P[k][0]);
        close(pipeC2P[k][1]);
    }
}
```

Above the `while(true)` bit in the child section should do the trick. So:

```
//child process
if (pid == 0)
{
    //find the pipe to read from.
    int childPid = getpid();
    int childIndex = children_ids[0] == childPid ? 0 : 1;
    std::cerr<<"in child "<<childPid<<" index "<<childIndex<<std::endl;
    //wait until the parent has written data
    fd_set rfds;
    int ready;
    for(int k=0;k<NUM_CHILDREN;k++){
        if(k!=childIndex){
            close(pipeP2C[k][0]);
            close(pipeP2C[k][1]);
            close(pipeC2P[k][0]);
            close(pipeC2P[k][1]);
        }
    }
    while(true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        //we are interested in the reading end
        FD_SET(pipeP2C[childIndex][0], &rfds);
        ready = select(pipeP2C[childIndex][0] + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ready > 0){
            std::cerr<<"ready"<<std::endl;

            //close the relevant writing end of the pipe from parent to child
            close(pipeP2C[childIndex][1]);
            //redirect input to stdin
            dup2(pipeP2C[childIndex][0], 0);
            close(pipeP2C[childIndex][0]);

            //close relevant reading end of the pipe from child to parent
            close(pipeC2P[childIndex][0]);
            //redirect output from stdout
            dup2(pipeC2P[childIndex][1], 1);
            close(pipeC2P[childIndex][1]);

            execl("/usr/bin/file","file", "-n", "-f", "-", (char *)NULL);

            //should never get here
            std::cerr<<"file failed"<<std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem! Should've thought about it :)